# WSL Output to Powershell Variable

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL(Ubuntu) on my Windows Powershell(5.1)

I'm using `cat` and `sed` to find strings in between two patterns.

```
wsl cat $LinuxPath/info.txt | wsl sed -n '/-----BEGIN KEY-----/,/-----END KEY-----/p'
```

If I use it as is, the output is as expected:

```
-----BEGIN KEY-----
some random
characters generated
by the system
-----END KEY-----
```

But if assign it to a variable, `$Key = wsl cat...` and display it by `Write-Host $Key`, the display would look like this:

```
-----BEGIN KEY----- some random characters generated by the system -----END KEY-----
```

Comment: `Write-Host ($Key -replace '\r?\n',[environment]::NewLine)`

Comment: Powershell is probably capturing the individual lines as strings in an array. You can recombine them with ``Write-Host ($key -join "`n")``.

Comment: Thanks! `-join "\`n"` worked for me!